# Android: No Application perform this action, why?

Tags: android, permissions

i want to browse all Audio files, but i am getting error like No application can perform this action.. this is my code for browse activity...

-->    private static final int SELECT_MUSIC = 1;
      String selectedImagePath;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.browse)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
            // select a file
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("music/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select File"), SELECT_MUSIC);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_MUSIC) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

and i have also added permission to menifest file::    READ_PHONE_STATE
what's problem?  any idea?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that **No Application perform that action**. Why? because **None of the installed Applications perform that action**. It has nothing to do with permissions.

You are probably running this on an emulator, which does not include any directory browser application.

Comment: i have also tried in device but result is same. what should i do?

Comment: Should shouldn't do that. That's it. What you are doing is something like saying to the OS: "ey, I need an app to browse the files!", and the system will answer: "ey, I don't have apps to do so". There are applications to do so, but you cannot know whether your users will have the app or not. So, what you have to do is creating your own file browser for your app :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`intent.setType("audio/*");` instead of `intent.setType("music/*");`

Then you can choose a track, not a playlist.

Could you find a way to choose a playlist?
I have the same problem, looking for a way to open and choose a playlist.

Answer (score 0):

The `setType` method is working with MIME type values only.
If you really just need the handling of music files "audio/" should be ok (as mentioned before). To be more flexible, you should try to detect the MIME code of the file.

Here is a code snippit how this may look like:

```
FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
type = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor("file://" + file.getPath());
```

Or (pre Gingerbread)

```
if (!file.getName().contains("."))
   return null;
String ext = (String) file.getName().subSequence(
file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1,
file.getName().length());

MimeTypeMap mimeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
type = mimeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
```

I usually use the combination of both methods (use the pre Gingerbread version if the first approach fails).